# MapView setCenter() not working properly

Tags: android, dictionary, location, android-mapview, center

I have an Activity, where is a MapView on part of screen. Here I always center location to given point. Then I have another activity, where is MapView on whole screen and I center to users location. When I came back from whole screen MapView activity to activity with MapView on part of a screen, I call setCenter() on MapView again. But now MapView isn't centered on right location but few meters elsewhere. When I use animateTo(), everything works as expected. Is it any setCenter() bug or how should I explain this strange behaviour to myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the working solution is to use this:

```
controller.setCenter(getPoint);
controller.animateTo(getPoint);
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess there may be multiple possibilities that the setCenter() does not work.  I have spent quite some time on my own setCenter problem.  The animateTo() does not solve my problem.  Actually, from the documentation of MapController, setCenter specifically "set the map view to the given center. There will be no animation", so setCentre() is like moving to that point without animation.

Eventually, the one that solve my problem seems to be: I need to call setCentre() AFTER calling setZoom() to set the zoom level.

More information: I am using OSMDroid's mapView with offline maps.

Comment: The animateTo() solution didn't make sense to me either so I tried this and it worked for me, so thanks!